# C# .Net MVC OpenXml

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, openxml

Am using memorystream and open xml. I am trying to download excel file. But I am seeing the following errors.

Repaired Part: /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml part with XML error.  Load error. Line 1, column 0.

We found a problem with some content .xlsx. Do you want us to try and recover as much as we can?

[Error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MO05U.png)

[Error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arcLh.png)

My Code:

```
        List<string> model = new List<string>();
        model.Add("t1");
        #region Create Excel
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

        #region Create Document
        SpreadsheetDocument doc = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(ms, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook, false);
        WorkbookPart workbookPart = doc.AddWorkbookPart();
        workbookPart.Workbook = new Workbook();
        WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
        worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet();
        #endregion Create Document

        #region Create Columns
        Columns workSheetColumns = new Columns();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {
            Column col = new Column();
            workSheetColumns.Append(col);
        }
        worksheetPart.Worksheet.AppendChild(workSheetColumns);
        workbookPart.Workbook.Save();
        #endregion Create Columns

        #region Arrange Sheet Data
        worksheetPart.Worksheet.Append(new SheetData());
        Sheets sheets = doc.WorkbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild(new Sheets());
        Sheet sheet = new Sheet() { Id = doc.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart), SheetId = 1, Name = "Report" };
        sheets.Append(sheet);
        workbookPart.Workbook.Save();
        SheetData sheetData = (SheetData)worksheetPart.Worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();
        #endregion Arrange Sheet Data

        #region Arrange Headers
        Row rw = new Row();
        sheetData.Append(rw);
        rw.RowIndex = UInt32Value.FromUInt32((UInt32)sheetData.Elements().Count());
        {
            Cell c = new Cell();
            c.DataType = CellValues.String;
            c.CellValue = new CellValue("Test");
            c.CellReference = "A" + rw.RowIndex.ToString();
            rw.Append(c);
        }
  
        #endregion Arrange Headers

        #region Add Rows
        foreach (var modelItem in model)
        {
            rw = new Row();
            sheetData.Append(rw);
            rw.RowIndex = UInt32Value.FromUInt32((UInt32)sheetData.ChildElements.Count);

            {
                Cell c = new Cell();
                c.DataType = CellValues.String;
                c.CellValue = new CellValue(modelItem);
                c.CellReference = "A" + rw.RowIndex.ToString();
                rw.Append(c);
            }

        }
        #endregion Add Rows

        #region Finalize
        worksheetPart.Worksheet.Save();
        workbookPart.Workbook.Save();
        doc.Close();
        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        #endregion Finalize
        #endregion Create Excel

        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = @"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet.main+xml";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Report.xlsx");
        Response.BinaryWrite(ms.ToArray());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.Close();
        Response.End();
```

Comment: Instead of using the low-level OpenXML SDK you can use a library like EPPlus, ClosedXML or NPOI that can easily fill a sheet from a List<T>, a DataTable or a data reader, eg `sheet.Cells.LoadFromCollection(someItems);`

Comment: I've tried. i see the same error